# R program returns "x invalid 'type' (closure) of argument i"

Tags: r

```
catair = airfares[,c(7,8,14,15,18)] #separates out categorical columns for pivot table
#VACATION

v = count(catair,'VACATION')

v = mutate(v, 
           pct = freq/sum(freq))
```

This is the error

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `pct`.
> x invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
> i Input `pct` is `freq/sum(freq)`.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Try `v <- mutate(v, pct = n/sum(n))` count will create two columns `VACATION` and `n` - there might be no `freq`column

Comment: it worked , thankyou so much

Comment: how can i get the frequency of it then, i mean frequency is needed

Comment: n is the frequency colums - n contains the number of each vacation

Comment: okay got it :-) thank you so much